# Losing Subscripts in Google Docs when exporting to PowerPoint

Tags: google-slides

When I'm saving my presentation in Google Docs as Microsoft PowerPoint, all the letters marked as subscripts appears as regular letters in the PowerPoint document.

Does anyone else notice this? (I didn't find anything about it on the web.)

Is there a workaround for this? It's really obnoxious to re-subscript all the letters again.

**edit:** [asked](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=1a325220cfaf52e4&hl=en) on Google official help forum. Will update here if there's an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed in the meantime by Google. I could see the subscripts and superscripts in Powerpoint 2007 correctly when I have exported [my test presentation](https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AZAYaFFUUZQxZGhocDM3ODRfMjZmN3p4NnZnag&hl=en) into PPT.